# Use Javascript to trigger show/hide external embeded resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-visualization

I have a (long) `<script>` element that displays a Google visualization. The code comes straight from Google; I have no way to change it.

I need the output of this hidden until the user clicks Show.

I had two attempts to achieve this goal:

1. If the script tag is processed inside a hidden DOM node, it fails to display when the containing node is shown.
2. If the script tag is dynamically inserted `jQuery('#parent-element').html('<script...>');` then it fails because it requires `document.write` which [cannot run asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255526/invoking-document-write) (no way to tell *where* in the document to write it)

The reason I need the show/hide buttons is because the output is displayed in a full-screen overlay (it is too big for the normal content area).

I would like a solution that works generically so my client can embed other "magic" html chunks provided by external SAAS (google, youtube, ...)

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: why does this need to be asynchronous?

Comment: @Asad it doesn't need to be async. In attempted solution (1) it wasn't async; but in attempted solution (2) it was async.

Comment: two downvotes? humph. It would be more constructive if down-voters left a comment explaining their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `display:none` use a invisible element (`visibility:hidden`).

`display:none` means that the element is not rendered as part of the DOM.
it is not loaded until the display property changes to something else.

`visibility:hidden` loads the element, but does not show it.

Comment: Thanks, but `visibility:hidden` does not take it out of page flow - I'd have a massive blank space where the content would be.

Comment: @artulrobot: can be easily fixed. just set the width/height to zero. later, when you change `visibility` to `visible`, also change the size (100px, 999px, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by positioning the `<script>`'s parent element absolutely and way off the viewport (css: `position:absolute; left:-10000px;` ).

Then I made the `fixed` overlay entirely separate (i.e. a sibling), hidden by default.

On show, the overlay is `fadeIn()`ed and on completion of the fade, the off-screen content element is set to `position:fixed; left: 24px; top: 24px;`.

On re-hide, the content is reset off screen and the overlay hidden with `fadeOut()`.

The overlay needs a lower `z-index` than the content.